# How to create new screen in gcp console, which will keep running?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, console, virtual-machine, screen

I want to keep my console running of gcp vm.
how can I create new screen.
I know the command to

> ```
> list of all screens is `screen -ls`
>
> opening an existing screen is `screen -r nameofscreen`
>
> closing the screen `ctrl ad`
> ```

but I don't know how to create new one?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new screen window, press “Ctrl-A” and “c“